Why are these values missing in Borgnakke-Sonntag Fundamentals of Thermodynamics properties table?

I understand some values are missing on tables because there are some places where the substance is not vaporized.
However I don't understand how can it be missing in the middle of other values like this.

Those same values are missing in the 1000 kPa table as well, there just isn't a line for them. Perhaps something related to how data is presented in other tables?

It could be a simple error in writing the table. In the table above there is no 450 K column, so maybe there wasn't supposed to be one in the table below either. But the editors forgot it and it went unnoticed in this version.
